# How to add json data in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

```
function addToCart(product_id, quantity, main) {
    quantity = typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1;
    main = typeof(main) != 'undefined' ? main : 0;
    view1 = $("#view1").val();
    cv_page = $("#cv_page").val();
    order_id = $("#order_id").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?option=com_payment&task=cart',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + quantity + '&main=' + main + '&view1=' + view1 + '&cv_page=' + cv_page + '&order_id=' + order_id,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $('.success, .warning, .attention, .information, .error, .fail').remove();
            if (json['success']) {
                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

                if (main == "1") {                  
                    window.location =$('#order-url').val();
                } else {
                    window.location =$('#form-url').val();
                }

            } else {
                $('#notification').html(json['message']);
            }
        }           
    });     
}
```

How to add this file in mysql database and how to define this

`url: 'index.php?option=com_payment&task=cart',`

And how to call this

```
<input type="hidden" id="order-url" value ="order.html?cv_page=1#order-title" />  
<input type="hidden" id="form-url" value ="form.html?cv_page=1#form_mark" />
```

Can anyone help me I just understand which is need to index.php file to run this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you are looking on how to build your index.php (the php file that is called from your AJax).

First, concerning the data that you sent, can I recommand you the following format?

```
data: {product_id.product_id , quantity: quantity [...]},
```

In your php file (index.php):

1- Check each parameters (example for product_id):

```
$product_id = null;
if(isset($_POST['product_id']) && !empty($_POST['product_id'])){
    product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
}
```

2- check if there is a missing parameter:

```
if($product_id === null || [...] ){
    echo json_encode(array(
        'error' => array(
            'msg' => "There is a missing parameter"
        ),
    ));
    exit();
}
```

3- Use your favorite way to input data in your database (example with PDO):
        $requete = "    INSERT INTO ".$this->NomTable_product." 
                            (product_id, ...)
                        VALUES 
                            (:product_id, :view_name, :id_page_index)";

```
    $requete = $this->customerPdo->prepare($requete);

    $requete->bindValue(':product_id', $product_id , PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $returnOperation = $requete->execute();
    $requete->closeCursor();
    return$returnOperation;
```

Also I will recommand you to be very careful concerning the data verification. You should check each one of your parameters before putting it in your Database. I don't know what you are currently doing to connect your database and enter data, but you can use PDO in order to improve this point.

Regards,